# Background and components stay behind bottom bar in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox, react-navigation-bottom-tab

In react native, devices with virtual navigation keys do not have any problems, while on phones with manual keys (e.g. Samsung A5,) the background and components are behind the bottom bar. When I give flex:1 or height:heightPercentageToDP(100) to my View, I have the same problem. how can i solve it? I'll be happy if you can help me.

i want to components and background start from the top of the bottom bar

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should add your code so it's easier to help you, or even an example screenshot to show your issue... but I will try to answer.

React Native has the Dimensions API which you can import in with your Views and Texts like so:
`import { View, Text, Dimensions } from "react-native";`

If you grab the height like this: `const deviceHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;` using `window` as the param will give you the height excluding the bar you mentioned. Using `screen` there would provide the entire height.

You could use the windows Dimension to calculate any margin or padding you might need based on your use case.

Comment: thank you for the answer it didn't work for me but i solved my problem and i replied to you a week ago but i guess for some reason my answer didn't arrive